# Incomplete robots.txt, what happens?

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt, google-crawlers

I have a page on a website, and don't have access to anything other that my page. The website is used to sell various small products.
After being with them for over a year, and having using google adwords to help promote myself, I noticed that none of the product's pages were indexed on google. When I noticed that the robots.txt for the site didn't contain much, and wondering if this has anything to do with it.

Product URLs follow this format:

```
www.example.com/myshopname/[product ID]?q=I[product ID]
```

And the robots.txt is simply:

```
Disallow: /*_escaped_fragment_
```

There's no user-agent. I'm wondering if this would have any effect on Google crawling my page, or if it would simply ignore the robots.txt as no user-agent was specified.

Comment: Get some more detailed information here: https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt

Comment: @Franco I read documentation on robots, nothing about incomplete robot.txt files. 
From what I know is that, you have to type in a user-agent first, then the disallow rule. I'm not sure what happens if no user-agent is given... do robots act as if user-agent is *, or will it simply ignore the disallow rule since a user-agent is not given.

If it were to act as user-agent being *, then how would the rule be applied? Since AJAX crawling is now deprecated, will it ignore that rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you some more info here:

The robots.txt file is a simple text file on your web server which tells webcrawlers if they can access a file or not.
You can always access this file because is not part of your server system files but is a part of your site.

In your case I don't know what this `/*_escaped_fragment_` means but :

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

**Will block the access to all the crawlers**

While this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Allow full access to your website.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /images/
```

Will block access to the specified folder

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /images
Allow: /images/my_photo.jpg
```

Even if you disallow a folder you can always give access to a specified file in that folder.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /assets.html
```

Will block access to the specified file

So the `star` means all crawlers if you want apply the directives to a specified crawler you need to do:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
```

If you are specifically interested on googlebot and you want to see if your robot.txt is blocking files or folders on your site just visit the https://developers.google.com/ so you can see if you are blocking page resources.

Is also necessary to say that while the robot.txt can be an useful tool for your SEO, the directives applied will be respected by all the regular crawlers.

Malicious crawlers do not care about those directives.

Comment: I already knew what robots.txt is for, how to use it, and documentation on it. My question was, how would an **incomplete** robots file be read.

Answer (score 1):

This robots.txt is invalid (according to the [original specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html)), because each record requires at least one `User-agent` and at least one `Disallow` line.

The specification doesn’t say that consumers should (try to) interpret invalid records.

So, speculation:

- Strict consumers will ignore this invalid record. For these consumers, your robots.txt will be equivalent to a non-existent robots.txt, which is equivalent to this one:

  ```
  User-agent: *
  Disallow:
  ```

  (i.e., everything is allowed)
- Polite consumers might assume that the author intended to have a `User-agent: *` for this record. For these consumers, your robots.txt will be equivalent to this one:

  ```
  User-agent: *
  Disallow: /*_escaped_fragment_
  ```

In any case, your robots.txt will (most likely) stop no consumer from crawling URLs whose paths start with `/myshopname/` (unless the URL contains `_escaped_fragment_`, in which case some consumers might stop crawling it, i.e., those that interpet `*` as wildcard; which is by the way not part of the original spec).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Guess if the robot crawls it will depend on how it tries to interpret this.